# Adding a total point system with watching of videos to earn the points

Tags: java, android

Before asking this question, yes I know how to code. My app is almost fully developed and properly working. I too need help and advice on some things though. So!

In my app I have an option were users can watch videos, and earn points from watching them. (3 Points per video). The user would watch the entire video and then afterwards would receive his points. Now I am inexperienced on how to actually add this point system. If anyone has done anything like this, I'd love some insight. Thank you!

**EDIT:** If anyone is wondering what kind of point system, I just need something basic like the one that "App Trailers" uses. The point where a user would watch the video, then earn points after the video has finished.

Comment: what problem you are facing in adding an `integer` point?

Comment: @Mohit the problem is actually adding the point system

Comment: can I know how you are generating points...i mean just concept..not  code..

Comment: what you mean by *point system* ?